# x86 $esp Changing Oddly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm disassembling some x86 assembly code compiled with GCC for an assignment.

Immediately before calling a function, I have:

```
$esp = 0xffffdbd0
```

Setting a breakpoint on the very first line of the function called (even before the `push`) gives:

```
$esp = 0xffffdbcc
```

After the push:

```
$esp = 0xffffdbc8
```

So why is `$esp` changing like that?  Theoretically, just going to a function shouldn't change the stack pointer, and then it changes after the `push`?  What's going on?

I have a guess, that it has to do with alignment, and that somehow some sort of alignment is going on behind my back with the `call` and `push` assembly instructions.  But that's a guess; I have no idea.

Can someone who knows clarify?

Comment: Learn the x86 instruction set. The CPU manuals from Intel and AMD contain pretty detailed descriptions of what each instruction does.

Comment: Yeah . . . I'm workin' on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute a `CALL` instruction, the address of the instruction immediately after the `CALL` is pushed onto the stack. This is so that when you execute a `RET` instruction, the program can jump back to the right address and continue executing instructions. Pushing this address onto the stack means that you can have nested `CALL`s and have no problems returning to the correct address at each `RET`.

Since this is a 32-bit system, 4 bytes will be pushed onto the stack:

```
0xffffdbd0 - 0xffffdbcc = 0x4
```

Answer (score 3):

The `call` instruction pushes the address of the first instruction after itself to the stack before jumping to the target location. This way, `ret` knows where to go after the function returns.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption

> Theoretically, just going to a function shouldn't change the stack
>   pointer

is plain wrong. Going to a function does exactly that: It changes the stack pointer, notably it pushes the return address on it. "Pushing" in x86 (and in almost every other arch) always means implicitly decrementing the stack pointer and storing the value to be pushed on it.

Comment: I meant just going to a symbol (I was thinking of function calling like a jmp), and going to the address of the function, before ebp is set to esp and esp is decremented.  I see now that the call function does more than just a jmp; thanks.